# Convert an array of strings to a vector of numbers

Tags: matlab

I have this:

```
d = {'2.5', '3.5'};
d = 
'2.5'    '3.5'
```

How do I convert it to a vector of numbers?

```
d = 2.5   3.5
```

Comment: str2num(d) says 'Requires string or character array input.'. There are many values in the actual array so don't to do it element by element.

Comment: has been answered many times, but see my answer on how to apply `str2num` (or better `str2double`) on each element of a cell array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you have a cell array of string values, you can use `cellfun` to apply `str2num` conversion on each entry. The output will be a vector/matrix of the converted values.

```
d = {'2.3','3.5'}
dVec = cellfun(@str2num, d);
```

However, you are better using `str2double` than `str2num.` From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

> Note: str2num uses the eval function to convert the input argument.
>   Side effects can occur if the string contains calls to functions.
>   Using str2double can avoid some of these side effects.

```
dVec = cellfun(@str2double, d);
```

**Update**: As @yuk points out, you can call `str2double()` directly on the cell array for the same output.

```
dVec = str2double(d);
```

Note that the same call with `str2num()` will give the *"must be a string or string array"* error.

Comment: You don't need cellfun. str2double perfectly works with cell arrays.

Comment: @yuk good point. updated. As a side-note, this applies only to `str2double()` though, and not `str2num()`.

Comment: str2double is around 10-20% slower than cellfun with string2mat.